# StoryBoard and initialization

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uistoryboard

Question: How do I perform custom initializations when using StoryBoards?

I have read several questions with the same keywords that are in my title, but could not find any answer. I beg your pardon if this question has already been asked or it is too basic: I have just started developing iOS apps.

Currently I have an application whose:

- `AppDelegate` reads from a source (currently a remote URL) two URLs that need to be displayed in instances of `UIWebView`;
- main controller is a `TabBarController` with two tabs, that are instances of `UIWebView`;
- the two `UIWebView` have methods (init and setter) for receiving the URL of the file they need to display. These two `UIWebView` display the URLs read by the `AppDelegate`.

I am trying to perform the same operations using a StoryBoard but do not know how to pass the `URL` of the content to the two `UIWebView`. I have read the answers concerning the `initWithCoder` method, but cannot figure out how to pass the parameters.

Is there anyone who figured out what I meant in my (incredibly confused) question who is also able to help me?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail exactly what you're doing?  Why can't the webviews handle reading from the URL themselves?  Do you ALWAYS have two tabs in the tab bar controller, and are they ALWAYS UIWebViews?

Comment: How can I pass the URL to each UIWebView?

I do not have only UIWebViews, I tried to build a simple example for my question.

Comment: Where are you getting the URL from?  Don't tell me "from the app delegate".  Tell me where the app delegate gets the url from.  How does the app delegate know which URLs you want to pass to the UIWebViews?

Comment: In the current implementation the AppDelegate connects to a remote URL and download a text file. After parsing, two UIViewControllers with UIWebView views are created and put in a TabBarController, which is then used as rootViewController of the window. 

However, my general question concerns how to pass parameters to ViewControllers put in a TabBarController when using StoryBoard.

I have checked various tutorials but they always use static or no data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the right place to do this is your ViewController. You should create an outlet of the UIWebView within your ViewController in order to be able to access them. Then to pass the URL to them you can use:

```
- (void)loadRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
```

I don't understand why you read remotely the URLs in your AppDelegate but you can access your AppDelegate from your ViewController if needed as follows:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say that "I don't understand why you read remotely…"? Is it the wrong place?

Comment: Yes.  The app delegate shouldn't be doing this things.  They have nothing to do with app delegation.

Comment: I wouldn't know where to put that code since it is related to the app initialization.

Comment: In any other class.  It can be an `NSObject` subclass even, but for the sake of organization, it definitely needs to be moved out of the app delegate.  I'm not entirely convinced it can't be done by the view controllers though.

Comment: It is obviously in a class different from the AppDelegate, but the data is downloaded before creating the views.

Comment: It's clearly not obvious, Antonio.  You've been very vague.  You haven't convinced me that this can't be handled by the view controllers.  Nonetheless, my answer explains how to get a reference to a view controller in a tab bar controller.

Comment: I agree with @nhgrif - there's no reason to do this in the AppDelegate. The best approach is probably starting the download when the ViewController is loaded (from viewDidLoad) and uploading the UIWebViews when the download is complete. In the meantime you should inform the user that your app is in the middle of something e.g. showing an UIActivityIndicatorView. If your concern is having the URLs downloaded before your views appear on screen - well doing the download in the AppDelegate doesn't guarantee this, as it depends on network.

Comment: Also there is the possibility that the download fails. What do you do in that case - you want probably handle that showing a error message I assume.

Comment: Thanks everyone. After working on the code a little bit more, I understood your concerns. The final implementation is basically similar to the one proposed by Tanzolone.

Answer (score 0):

On the general question of accessing references to view controllers in a tab bar controller...

A tab bar controller has a public property called `viewControllers`, which is an array of view controllers which the tab bar controller contains.

You can access elements of this array just as you would any other array, but in this case, they're references to all your view controllers.

```
[tabBarController.viewControllers firstObject]; 

[tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:3];

for(UIViewController *vc in tabBarController.viewControllers) {
    if([@"MyFirstVC" isEqualToString:vc.title]) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

etc. etc. etc.